# ¿Cómo eliminar el icono por defecto de un elemento img? (imagen no encontrada)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Me gustaría evitar que salga el icono que sale por defecto cuando no se encuentra una imagen en un elemento `< img >`. El texto de la propiedad **alt** no me importa tanto pero si también puedo evitar que salga mucho mejor.

Este es mi elemento (la propiedad src se establece dinamicamente):

```
<img id="img_id" alt="0">
```

Y asi es como se ve sin imagenes y con imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabría como hacer esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imaginando que tienes varias imágenes con una clase. Es posible ocultarlas usando el evento `error` con jQuery:

```html
<img class="image" src="http://orig14.deviantart.net/61ac/f/2011/271/9/7/goku_icon_by_pinkpanda191-d4b8dhe.jpg">
<img class="image" src="nada">
<img class="image" src="http://orig02.deviantart.net/1e49/f/2011/344/9/c/goku_icon_by_cyberchimchar-d4iomxv.png">
```

Como puedes ver, la segunda imagen viene de una fuente inválida. Ahora observa como la oculto usando el evento `error`:

```js
var images = $(".image");

$(images).on("error", function(event) {
    $(event.target).css("display", "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="image" src="http://orig14.deviantart.net/61ac/f/2011/271/9/7/goku_icon_by_pinkpanda191-d4b8dhe.jpg">
<img class="image" src="nada">
<img class="image" src="http://orig02.deviantart.net/1e49/f/2011/344/9/c/goku_icon_by_cyberchimchar-d4iomxv.png">
```

O tal vez prefieras reemplazar la imagen con un placeholder para mantener la estructura:

```js
var images = $(".image");

$(images).on("error", function(event) {
    $(event.target).attr("src", "https://image-placeholder.com/images/actual-size/200x200.png");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="image" src="http://orig14.deviantart.net/61ac/f/2011/271/9/7/goku_icon_by_pinkpanda191-d4b8dhe.jpg">
<img class="image" src="nada">
<img class="image" src="http://orig02.deviantart.net/1e49/f/2011/344/9/c/goku_icon_by_cyberchimchar-d4iomxv.png">
```

Yo estoy usando un placeholder en línea, pero puedes cambiarlo por la imagen que consideres necesaria.

Comment: sin duda muy completa la respuesta y en efecto html y css no puede saber si existe el error de carga en la img por lo cual se usa Jquery o JavaScript como los machos... lol...!!

Comment: Hola!! gracias por responder!! No se pede revertir de alguna forma? Es decir, en esos rectangulos pongo y quito imagenes al azar... pero si uso el evento "onerror" el  "display=none" permace aunque vuelva a poner otra imagen en ese rectangulo... asi que la siguiente imagen no se ve... voy a intentar probar con el placeholder a ver como queda.

Comment: Con el placeholder funciona mejor... lo que pasa es que así todo lo que habia programado no sirve para nada porque se basaba en si propiedad src tenia o no tenia un valor dado... :-( ... De todas formas voy a dar por buena tu resuesta porque si soluciona el problema de mi pregunta... voy  a tener que currarmelo un poco y solucionar el problema del "display:none"... muchas gracias!!

Comment: Ok, solucionado!! Para mi caso concreto fue mejor usar **$(event.target).css("visibility", "hidden");** que **display:none**, pero en esecia tu respuesta me ha solucionado el problema!! Muchas Gracias!! @César

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar con `onerror`

```
<img
   src="no_encuentra"
   onerror="this.onerror=null; 
   this.src='https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/AFoAAOSw5e5cbgL6/s-l400.jpg';"
/>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta sfr!!

Answer (score 3):

Saludos podrias usar algo como esto:

```html
<h4>CON IMAGEN</h4>
<img src="https://www.elcomercio.com/files/article_main/uploads/2017/03/17/58cca4a396a07.jpeg" alt="ambato"><br>
<h4>SIN IMAGEN</h4>
<img src="broken" onerror="this.style.display='none'" alt="error">
```

Para mayor detalle del onerror te sugiero revisar esto:
[OnError](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Diego!!